# styled ToolTip causes 'Function components cannot be given refs' warning

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

Good morning,

I've a styled mui tooltip component to create a custom theme for it.
When I use it, I get the following warning in the browsers console:

```
client.js:1 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `Styled(Component)`.
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/components/lightToolTip.tsx:23:28)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-c39617d8.browser.esm.js:60:66)
    at _c1 (webpack-internal:///./src/components/lightToolTip.tsx:49:27)
    at LinkComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:113:26)
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-c39617d8.browser.esm.js:60:66)
    at Box (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/createBox.js:37:72)
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-c39617d8.browser.esm.js:60:66)
    at Box (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/createBox.js:37:72)
    at div
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-
[...]
```

So code looks like

```
const LightTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }: TooltipProps) => (
    <Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />
))(({ theme }) => ({
    [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.neutral[900],
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)',
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[1],
        fontSize: 11,
    },
}));
```

After some google search I already tried to wrap the styled component:

```
import { Tooltip, TooltipProps, styled, tooltipClasses } from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';

const InnerLightTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }: TooltipProps) => (
    <Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />
))(({ theme }) => ({
    [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.neutral[900],
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)',
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[1],
        fontSize: 11,
    },
}));

export const LightTooltip = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, TooltipProps>((props, ref) => {
    return <InnerLightTooltip {...props} ref={ref} classes={{ popper: props.className }} />;
});

LightTooltip.displayName = 'LightTooltip';
```

I've no idea why this warning occurs and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Material-UI`  with `styled-components` or `@emotion/styled`, wrapping a MUI component with styled sometimes produces the warning you've encountered. This happens especially when the MUI component internally forwards refs.

try this code :

```
import { Tooltip, TooltipProps, styled, tooltipClasses } from '@mui/material';

const LightTooltip = styled(
  React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, TooltipProps>((props, ref) => {
    const { className, ...other } = props;
    return <Tooltip {...other} ref={ref} classes={{ popper: className }} />;
  })
)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.neutral[900],
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[1],
    fontSize: 11,
  },
}));

LightTooltip.displayName = 'LightTooltip';
```